# Unexpected error:404 during websocket connection

Tags: java, javascript, android, websocket

I tried to create a websocket chat application using apache tomcat.
but when i tried to open a websocket connection using this line,

```
webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + socket_url + ":" + port+ "/WebMobileGroupChatServer/chat?name=" + name);
```

and i also included the SocketServer.java using

```
@ServerEndpoint("/chat")
```

but it is firing a error when WebSocket is created,

WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.157:8080/WebMobileGroupChatServer/chat?name=sdf' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

i referred the code from [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/)

How can i solve it?

Comment: try to see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24790108/3587326

Comment: my tomcat version is 7, but that is thee solution for tomcat v7.0.47