# GWT 2.8 websocket support

Tags: gwt, websocket, jetty, gwt-2.8

Does jetty server in gwt 2.8 support websocket now? As I know it did not support before. If there is a positive answer, then how to make it work? Stripping out jetty-8 and replaceing it with jetty-9 is not a good idea I think.

Answer (score 1):

> then how to make it work?

I want to elaborate a bit on this after the GWT 2.8.0 release. The only thing required for using `javax.websocket` is the knowledge of the Jetty version packaged with GWT and the following set of Maven dependencies (see also the Jetty WebSocket examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/master/javax.websocket-example/pom.xml)):

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <sdm.jetty.version>9.2.14.v20151106</sdm.jetty.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
        <version>${sdm.jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${sdm.jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </depencies>
</project>
```

Make doubly sure that the scope is *provided* - for the former two this will mean they are not packaged into the final app - you will be requiring those only when running the SuperDev-Mode (SDM). If`java.websocket-api`was on your classpath probably the annotation-based configuration will not work at all (at least in embedded Tomcat and Jetty) due to the annotations being picked up by the wrong class loader (see also related question [WebSocket 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779477/websocket-404-error) for more info on this topic).

Answer (score 0):

GWT 2.8 has switched to Jetty 9.2, **and** now supports Servlets 3.1 servlets container initializers, which I think are being used to setup WebSockets.
I haven't tried it but I suppose that you can now have WebSockets in DevMode, provided you add the required dependencies to the classpath.

You can also simply use a separate server rather than the one embedded into DevMode.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I found two arguments about this issue:
            1. If you follow this link [https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.8.0-beta1/dev/build.xml] you will see that jetty version is NOT 9.2, but 8.1.12;
            2. In log trace of my project, every time I run it I see this: "INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT".
        Where did you get information which claims that jetty version was 9.2?

Comment: I merged the change earlier this year and unbundled Jetty from the Maven artifacts soon after. This was after beta1.