# Unable to connect websocket getting error - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, websocket

I am trying to create a web socket in java. However I am getting error "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
(anonymous)" when I am trying to connect to the socket using java script.

I have tried using provided scope with the javax.websocket, also tried switching to tomcat7-websocket jar as suggested in answers here [WebSocket 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779477/websocket-404-error/24790108) . I am still getting the same error. Thank you for the help in advance.

I also tried removing the .m2 directory, that didn't help either.

I am using this code on java end

```
@ServerEndpoint("/webSockTest")
public class ServerTest {

    private static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        peers.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session) {
        peers.remove(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage(String message, Session session) {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

And trying to connect using:

```
new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/demo/webSockTest")
```

Comment: `@ServerEndpoint("/webSockTest")` -> `ws://localhost:8080/demo/webSockTest` where does this `demo/webSocketTest` come from? is that correct?

Comment: @ruhul Surely, `demo` is the context-path of the application and therefore is a part of the URL but not the endpoint URI, which is context-relative.

Comment: @ruhul yeah demo is context-path of the application